# ¿Cómo crear múltiples tablas en base a una variable?

Tags: r, timeseries

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada "imd" con mas de 53mil variables:

```
idta    date_month       mean_intensitat
<int>   <date>               <dbl>
1       2003-01-01            703.
1       2003-02-01            701.
1       2003-03-01            687.
1       2003-04-01            732.
1       2003-05-01            754.
1       2003-06-01            898.
```

Me gustaría generar una tabla por cada 'idta' distinto pero hay unos 300 diferentes, y los números no son correlativos, es decir, no llega hasta el 300. Me gustaría generar un código que me cree las tablas repetitivamente sin tener que hacerlo manualmente, pero soy demasiado novato para saber como resolver esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dividir cualquier `data.frame` en múltiples, puedes usar `split()`, en tu caso:

```
split(df, df$idta)
```

Como entrada tenemos el `data.frame` a dividir, y el criterio de la división, que en este caso será por cada cambio en `idta`, tener en cuenta que los datos ya vengan ordenados por esta columna, sino se generará más de un grupo por `idta`. El resultado final será una lista, que es la forma adecuada para manejar cada `data.frame` por separado.

Ejemplo con `mtcars`, separando por `cyl`:

```
lista_df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Luego, accedemos a cada elemento, por nombre o por el índice numérico, en este ejemplo si queremos listar el `data.frame` de los autos de 4 cilindros:

```
# Podemos usar cualquiera de estas formas
lista_df $`4`
lista_df [[1]]

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es mucho más eficiente de lo que quería hacer. Hay alguna manera ahora de eliminar de la lista creada aquellos data.frame que no cumplan un numero determinado de nrow?

Comment: Si, siguiendo con el ejemplo de `mtcars`  para eliminar elementos que contengan menos de 8 filas: `lista[lapply(lista, nrow) < 8] <- NULL`